# Game development mysql conditions

Tags: javascript, mysql

When a player moves an item to his character the item type(type) is sent to the server

in the case where a player equips an armband the type = "bracelet" Id like it to attempt to put the item id in the  leftbracer column under the game_moblist (players and badguys in game) table first then the right if the left has an item_id already.  I use the value = 0 to indicate an empty slot.

```
if (type=="bracelet"){
    to_sql="UPDATE game_moblist SET leftbracer"="+item_id+" WHERE id="+player_id
}
```

previously I was using a select first but I'd like to do it in 1 query.  Thanks.

Comment: You have an `=` that probably should be a `+`. But I don't get it. Are you building your SQL client side ?

Comment: It will make for a slow game if you use the MySQL as your state repository.  You should keep the game state in a local data structure and backup that state to the DB as necessary.  Sounds like you're putting the logic of whether to equip the bracer in the left or right hand in the database.

Comment: whats your server side language? your syntax looks wrong, or maybe im just not used to it

Comment: Many big games use MySQL as the only repository without intermediary storage but they usually use PHP or another server side language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use an IF to se if leftbracer = 0, and set the value to either the new item id or keep the old value

```
UPDATE game_moblist SET 
   rightbracer = IF(leftbracer = 0, rightbracer, :item_id),
   leftbracer = IF(leftbracer = 0, :item_id, leftbracer );
```

Comment: you should make sure that rightbracer is also empty before assigning :item_id to that column.